# How do I get default.aspx working

Tags: asp.net

My ISP needs a default.aspx page for my website.  They said rename the index.aspx.

Problem is default is a keyword.  If I rename index to default in index.aspx.cs file is gives the default keyword error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace china
{
    public partial class default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How to get around it.  Any idea.

Regards
Tea

Comment: Have you tried @default? I am not sure if this will work, just the first thing that got on my mind.

Comment: you can use Default with capital D

Comment: You most likely need to rename the class in the CodeBehind attribute in your Default.aspx page from index to default as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One other way would be rename your file with `Default.aspx`, **Uppercase `D`**, this will remove the error since `Default` in C# is different to default **(case senstive)** and would work for the file system as well. *(since file system on Windows would be case insenstive)*

Otherwise rename **only the file name, not the class name** in the code. One way to do that would be to rename on File Explorer, but remember to correctly specify the file name in CodeBehind attribute in ASPX page.